# Where can I find the possible off-topic close reasons at a given site?

Tags: support, close-reasons

With the down-the-line goal of [streamlining question closure](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/streamlining-question-closure-approximate-roadmap) at Chinese.SE, I want to identify the off-topic close reasons at the other language sites.  I want to understand their decisions, and consider the precise wording of their close reasons.

**Question**: Where can I find the possible off-topic close reasons at a given site?

Starting with a random closed question at Korean.SE, I'm finding it unhelpful for my purpose (presumably because I don't have reputation there):

> [image: screenshot of a closed question at Korean.SE: "This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers."]

Clicking on the link brings me [here](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), which says:

> You can see this list of off-topic subjects for this site by [viewing this help center article](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

This links to the on-topic page (not the list of close reasons, nor the generic [don't ask](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page), which is again not helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find them in SEDE; since they can be quite long, it's best to enable the 'Text-only results' option. [Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/korean/query/1271057?opt.textResults=true):

[image]

This has the advantage that you can see *all* the guidance texts, not just the one for flaggers/close voters; you can of course see those when opening the flag dialog:

[image]

Another advantage of SEDE is that you can easily compare different sites; [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/korean/query/1271059/off-topic-close-reasons?Sites=English%2CELL%2CGerman%2CFrench%2CSpanish%2CItalian%2CKorean%2CChinese%2CUkrainian%2CRussian%2CEsperanto%2CLatin%2CPortuguese%2CJapanese&opt.textResults=true) shows all off-topic reasons on the language sites that I know of.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  The other language sites are: <strike>Latin, Ukrainian, Portuguese, Esperanto</strike> (they have no off-topic close reasons?), LanguageLearning, ConLang (and there's also a Russian Russian site https://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I left out Language Learning because it's a cross-language site, Constructed Languages because it's rather different and Rus.SE since I assume you don't read Russian :) But feel free to add those to the parameter.